# How to perform loose equality operator in c#?

Tags: javascript, c#, operators

Is there a JavaScript  loose equality operator’s `==` equivalent in  C# ? or a function?

Example

```
// JavaScript ‘==' operator 
console.log(21 == 21); //true
console.log(21 == "21");  // true
console.log("food is love"=="food is love"); //true
console.log(true == 1);  //true
console.log(false == 0);  //true
```

Comment: Actually quite interesting question. I'm not sure there is, however you can overwrite the "==" operation as far as I know, with that you could achive something similar with classes.

Comment: no, because the concept is not applicable. you _can't_ compare, for example, `int` and `string` without explicit conversion. so - unless you're throwing away all the benefits of strong, static typing by using `dynamic`, you have to know at _compile time_ what types you are comparing.

Comment: Thank you, now more clear for me.

Comment: @Vulpex can't overload/redefine operators for types you don't create though (all the given examples use built in types, with a fixed definition of `==`)

Comment: @CaiusJard thus the addition of `with classes` but reading it over again I agree, I could've made it more clear that it only works with non built in types. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but you could write one and have a bunch of overloads for your cases.. Such as these that do bool/int compare:

```
static class Ext {
    public static bool Eq(this bool a, int b) => b.Eq(a);

    //e.g. a!=0 converts 0 to false, other to true, then compare of bool:bool is possible
    public static bool Eq(this int a, bool b) => b == (a != 0); 
}

Console.WriteLine(false.Eq(1));
```

If you do them as extension methods then they become like `a.Eq(b)` rather than `Eq(a, b)` so they read more like `a == b`